# How do I verify if the sudokus lines do have all 9 digits?

Tags: python, path, sudoku

Could someone please give me advice of how to start my code? I am supposed to verify if a text document containing rows of 9 numbers do have all 9 digits. If so, my code should say True, otherwise False.

Here is one of the text document examples

```
5,3,4,2,7,6,9,1,8
6,2,8,1,9,5,3,4,7
1,7,9,3,4,8,5,6,2
8,5,2,7,6,1,4,9,3
4,9,6,8,5,3,7,2,1
7,1,3,9,2,4,8,5,6
9,6,1,5,3,7,2,8,4
2,8,6,5,1,9,6,3,5
3,4,5,6,8,2,1,7,9
```

Code must say False
Thank you very much

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code.

Comment: Why should it say False for that input?

Comment: because at the 8th line, there is two 3 and two 5, so there is not all 9 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (ofcourse you need to read from file and that's left to you):

```
s = '''5,3,4,2,7,6,9,1,8
6,2,8,1,9,5,3,4,7
1,7,9,3,4,8,5,6,2
8,5,2,7,6,1,4,9,3
4,9,6,8,5,3,7,2,1
7,1,3,9,2,4,8,5,6
9,6,1,5,3,7,2,8,4
2,8,6,5,1,9,6,3,5
3,4,5,6,8,2,1,7,9'''

for x in s.split('\n'):
    print(''.join(sorted(x.split(','))) == '123456789')

# True
# True                                                        
# True                                                        
# True                                                        
# True                                                        
# True                                                        
# True                                                       
# False                                                       
# True
```

This checks whether each line contains all numbers from `1` to `9` in any order, giving out a `True` in that case else a `False`.